# How to secure client data in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, security

I have developed a single page AngularJS application. For data retrieval/storage, it communicates with REST APIs over https. As per client requirement, i need to implement Client Authentication. i.e., As the application is based on REST APIs, how can we ensure that the request made to API is from a valid client and not from fiddler or a tempered client.

the current approach is:

1> configure a client secret and a key in the angular app.

2> authenticate the client by requesting a token from server using this client secret and key.

3> server checks this secret and key, if validates, responds with a newly generated token.

4> all further requests from angularjs app would carry this token in header, to ensure that the request is from a valid client.

But it is not good enough, as attacker can easily capture the requests using fiddler and also can easily read the client secret and key. or can debug using firebug.

Is there any secure way to authenticate the client app?

Comment: Jwt tokens and jwe are good options imo.

Comment: Do you have any session kind of thing like User login validation on your server? I mean accessing those REST calls need any user authentication before?

Answer (score 0):

No security possible in the case if your REST API call is been shield by any User Authentication. I mean if User need to put Username/Password then they are able to call those API then you can implement some security.

But if your requirement like follows :

Any GUEST user with any browser open your application pages, which intern call your REST API.

Then there is no security. Since any attacker can intercept your Request/Response and call it further.

**Note : From security prepective, Whatever a Browser can do, any good attacker can do the same.**

But if you shield REST CALL Pages with username/password validation, then you can restrict the calls from server side with proper session validation.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Web Tokens (JWT - pronounced *jot*) might be what you're looking for. Auth0 has a swell [blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) that specifically addresses AngularJS + JWT.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trust the client to validate anything. If the user is using Firebug or Fiddler to "trick" your application then all you can do is verify the information server side to ensure it is valid.

You can trust the client to keep the user's session safe (to some extent), but if you can't trust the user then you can't trust anything the client sends to you.

If you need to ensure the integrity of a piece of data that is held client side you can use a MAC (Message Authentication Code) which is effectively a hash of the message appended to a server-side secret key that can be later verified. Sometimes this is (incorrectly) called signing. JWTs are the current standard to accomplish this.

It depends at the end of the day what threat you are trying to keep your application safe against - if it is a game with high scores that runs on the client, there's not much you can do to prevent the user from altering their score before it is sent to the server. If you need to trust such data, run it server side.